# hide part of image with css

Tags: css, image, hide

In a responsive design, I want to be able to hide part of an image using CSS for wide screens but have the entire image present so that I can change the image proportions with a media query to display the whole image for small screens. I've set-up a sample of what I wanted with a simple page but it's not working - the whole image is always displayed. The sample page is http://longinsurance.biz/temp.html; the goal is to display the top 82% of the image.

Can anyone suggest what I've done wrong or how to make it work?

Thanks!

Comment: You might be able to do something if it was a background image...is that an option?

Comment: You should post your code... a major part of SO is the potential to help other people with a similar question in the future. If that link goes down, how will it help anyone else?

Comment: You'll likely continue to get down-voted until you do.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to hide parts of an image, here's what to do.

**Image container CSS**

```
.image-container {
width: 80%; /* Chosen width */
height: 80%; /* Chosen height */
overflow: hidden; /* Cuts off whatever goes beyond the container */
}
```

**The image CSS to cut off the left side of the image**

```
.image-container img {
width: 100%; /* Fits the given width of the image container */
height: auto; /* Reduces deterioration because the height isn't forced */
margin: 0 0 0 -5px; /* The minus cuts off(hides) parts of the image */
}
```

**For the media query:** Use the same CSS and adjust the dimensions as needed.

**Note:** The higher the minus number, the more it cuts off.